# How to exclude the deleted file in git log command?

Tags: git, bash, delete-file, git-log

I need to exclude the deleted file in git log. I use the command `git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format:eee6ce6` to get the changed file name in last that commit.  I using [pre-receive](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/block_file_extensions.sh) hook to block the specific file type committing. Above command listed all file which has modified.

But I wanna allow the user to remove the specific file types. How can I do this?

- I tried this `git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format:eee6ce6-filter=d`  command too, But it also listing the deleted file.
- This `git log -1 --diff-filter=d --name-only` perfectly works. But the it giving `commit ID, author name, date` also. I want only the file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the names of deleted files in the last commit using `git diff`:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D HEAD~1
```

Comment: here what `HEAD^` represent? whether commit ID?

Comment: `HEAD^` means the commit before `HEAD`. So you get the difference between that and `HEAD`, in other words the changes in the last commit. Btw I replaced `HEAD^` with `HEAD~1`, it means exactly the same thing, but it's more portable (`HEAD^` doesn't work in DOS).